# Select div WITH specific attr and NOT specific value

Tags: jquery, attr

I try to select all the divs that have a specific attr but this attr is not a specific one.

```
$("[data-minut = '23']") // this works
```

It seems that this selects everything else but attr 23. I want to select all the div that have the attr data-minute but this attr is not 23:

```
$("[data-minut != '23']")
```

Here is the example to check: http://jsfiddle.net/3jbf2wwh/

jQUERY:

```
$("div").click(function() { 
    $("[data-minut != '23']").css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

CSS:

```
.blue {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:80px; height:30px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="blue" data-minut='23'></div>
<div class="blue" data-minut='24'></div>
<div class="blue" data-minut='25'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works if you add `div` in your selector.  Otherwise it also changes the `body` to a background color of yellow also because you don't tell jQuery that you only want to change the color of div's without the specified attribute so it will change the color of every node that doesn't contain that attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/3jbf2wwh/3/

```
$("div").click(function() { 
    $("div[data-minut != '23']").css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `:not` or `.not()`

```
$("[data-minut]:not([data-minut=23])")
// or
$("[data-minut]").not("[data-minut=23]")
```

`not` removes the specified selector from the collection. Here elements that have `data-minut=23` is excluded and others are included.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got it working as expected, by adding `div` in the beginning of the selector:

```
$("div").click(function() { 
    $("div[data-minut != '23']").css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

Now all divs that have data data-minut attribute and its value different from 23 are being highlighted with `yellow` `background-color`. If you asking why it's working, well I'm still trying to figure this out, and I'd welcome comments and assistance from some of the more seasoned jQuery veterans out there to point out why this is working :-) ... perhaps it's something to do with the fact that selector is more specific.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/3jbf2wwh/2/)

Comment: Why did you copy my answer 5 minutes after I wrote it?

Comment: @HowardRenollet, just by coincidence we had the same answer and I didn't copy it! On top of that, I think I spent at least a couple of minutes on writing some rationale why the solution works - I wish I'd the jQuery skill to writhe a thorough explanation like your answer. Before I published my answer I still thought that Amit Jokim's was the only answer out there. So my comments weren't trying to be sarcastic in anyway, only a bit humorous to point out my inability to provide a thorough answer. Btw, I gave you upvote :-)

Comment: it's cool, it happens.  I've had the same thing happen to me where I'm working very diligently on an answer then as soon as I submit it, someone else already posted the exact same thing.  It's cool, I just had to call you out on it :-)

Comment: @HowardRenollet Ok, no worries :-)